# Change WPF Combobox arrow using a data trigger

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am using a multi-select combobox that I found on CodeProject [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF].

I am attempting to change the shape of the arrow depending on whether or not all of the items are selected. However I have been unable to correctly reference the x:Name of Arrow in the setter.

Here is the code I've been trying to modify:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Z_Sys_UI.System.MultiSelectComboBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<ComboBox
    x:Name="MultiSelectCombo"  
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                       >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Tag="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"
                       Click="CheckBox_Click"           />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Grid >
                <ToggleButton 
                    x:Name="ToggleButton" 
                   Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    Focusable="false"                           
                    ClickMode="Press" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border
              x:Name="Border" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              CornerRadius="2"
              Background="White"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" />
                                <Border 
                x:Name="BorderComp" 
              Grid.Column="0"
              CornerRadius="2" 
              Margin="1" 
             Background="White"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                                           Background="White" Padding="3" />
                                </Border>
              <Path 
              x:Name="Arrow"
              Grid.Column="1"     
              Fill="Black"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z">
                                </Path>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ToggleButton.Template>
                </ToggleButton>
                <Popup 
                    Name="Popup"
                    Placement="Bottom"                        
                    AllowsTransparency="True" 
                    Focusable="False"  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                    PopupAnimation="Slide">
                    <Grid 
                              Name="DropDown"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  
                        MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                        <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder" 
                               BorderThickness="1" Background="White"
                                BorderBrush="Black"/>
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" DataContext="{Binding}">
                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectAll, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="false" >
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0 0 L 2 2 L 8 0 Z" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Template>
</ComboBox>
```

Right now it is giving errors that say The name Arrow is not recognized, and the member Data is not recognized or is not accessible.

It's also possible that the SelectAll path that I'm trying to trigger off of does not work either. The CodeProject code didn't seem to have that property fully implemented. I'll deal with that possibility later.

Thanks in advance for any answers or suggestions.

Comment: A trigger that changes controls that exist inside the ToggleButton template has to be in the ToggleButton template itself. But then how does it bind to properties of the ComboBox? If you can't get an AncestorType binding to work on a DataTrigger inside the ToggleButton's ControlTemplate, I'd try to take the trigger you've got and change the entire template of the ToggleButton. Just make two copies of the ToggleButton ControlTemplate, one with each version fo the arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `Arrow` is out of scope in the `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate`, because it's defined in the `ToggleButton` `ControlTemplate`. The solution turns out to be easy: Just put the trigger in the template where the target control is in scope.

```
<ToggleButton.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>

            <!-- snip snip snip -->
            <!-- snip snip snip -->
            <!-- snip snip snip -->

            <Path 
                x:Name="Arrow"
                Grid.Column="1"     
                Fill="Black"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
                >
            </Path>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger 
                Binding="{Binding Path=SelectAll, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                Value="false" >
                <Setter 
                    TargetName="Arrow" 
                    Property="Data" 
                    Value="M 0 0 L 2 2 L 8 0 Z"  
                    />
            </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ToggleButton.Template>
```

I'm assuming that `SelectAll` is a boolean dependency property, and a member of `MultiSelectComboBox`, because that seems to be implied by what you're doing with it. Here's my dependency property definition:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectAllProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectAll", typeof(bool), typeof(MultiSelectComboBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

And here's the test XAML I used:

```
<StackPanel
    Orientation="Vertical"
    >
    <CheckBox Content="SelectAll" x:Name="SelectAllCheckBox" />
    <local:MultiSelectComboBox 
        SelectAll="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=SelectAllCheckBox}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: So far so good, thanks. Putting the trigger in the template where the target control is in scope fixed the xaml errors that I was getting. `SelectAll` is a boolean dependency property and I'll see if that works in the next step.

Comment: It's all good. I implemented your xaml change and it worked the first time I tried it. I had already done some modifying of the existing code to make sure that SelectAll would be set properly.

Comment: @dev1998 Good news!

Comment: what does Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" mean?

Comment: @Hacki Ask the mods.

Comment: @15ee8f99-57ff-4f92-890c-b56153 what do you mean?